# Меню пуск и поиск открываются вместе, как исправить?

Tags: windows

Столкнулся с проблемой, пуск и поиск открываются вместе.

Решил ответить тут, может кому-то поможет...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

**Заходим в ветку реестра:**

Компьютер\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search

**Параметр:** ImmersiveSearch=0 или удалить.